# Suggestions for configuring the path to openssl.cnf in Apache Lounge installed on drive D:

Tags: windows, apache, openssl

I installed Apache Lounge on the D drive of my Windows operating system and noticed that the `openssl.cnf` file is being read from the default location at `C:\Apache24\conf` instead of the correct location at `D:\conf`.

I've checked Apache configuration files, but I couldn't find where I can specify the path to `openssl.cnf` to be read from `D:\conf`. This issue is affecting my ability to configure certain SSL aspects for the Apache server.

I have reviewed relevant configuration files such as `httpd.conf` or `httpd-ssl.conf`. I've also attempted to find specific information or settings in the Apache Lounge documentation, but I couldn't find details on how to change the path to `openssl.cnf`.

I want to know how I can modify the Apache Lounge configuration to specify the correct path for the `openssl.cnf` file located in `D:\conf`.

Additional information:

1. The version of Apache Lounge I'm using is: [`2.4.58 win64 VS17`](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/)
2. Operating System: `Windows 11`

I've tried to review the available online documentation, but I couldn't find clear information about this issue.